# Prove that the normed spaces $(C[0,1], \| \cdot\|_2)$ and $(C[a,b], \|\cdot \|_2)$ where $\| \cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm are isometric.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Essentially I'm looking for a bijection $f: C[0,1]\to C[a,b]$ such that$$\|f(x) \|_2=\| x\|_2$$ I don't know how to go about finding this function, but I do know that it is possible.
$$\| x \|_2 = \sqrt{\int_a^b x(t)^2\,dt} 
$$

What if the norms in question were:
 $$\| x\|_{\infty}= \sup_{t \in [a,b]}|x(t)|$$
 $$\| x \|_1 = \int_a^b |x(t)| \, dt$$

How would these bijections look if asked to prove the "isometricity" of $$(C[0,1], \| \cdot\|_i) \text{     and    } (C[a,b], \|\cdot \|_j) i\neq j\ \ ; i,j\in{1,2,\infty}$$

Comment: What is the euclidean norm on the space of functions on $[a,b]$? Is it $\sqrt{\int_a^b f(x)^2dx}$? What you've written is usually called the sup-norm.

Comment: Thats exactly it ! Thank you !

Comment: You're using the letter $f$ to refer to two different things: first a function from $C[0,1]$ to $C[a,b]$ (so that $x$ and $f(x)$ are functions) and second as a function whose domain is $[a,b]$ (so that $x$ and $f(x)$ are numbers). Could I suggest writing $\|x\|_\infty=\sup\limits_{t\in[a,b]} |x(t)|$ and $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\int_a^b x(t)^2\,dt}\,{}$?  That way the notation is consistent. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I think I edited accordingly.

Comment: It seems that you're confusing notations somewhat. An element in $C[a,b]$ is usually denoted by $f$ or $g$, which means that it's unwise to use the same symbol for a map between two such spaces. I would advice you to use, for instance, one of the greek letters $\phi$ or $\psi$ for this purpose. Then you can write $\|\phi(f)\|_2=\|f\|_2$, and further specify what $\|f\|_2$ means in terms of $\int f(x)dx$. Of course, using $f$ as the bijection, $x$ as a function and $t$ as a variable works as well. Just be consistent.

Comment: You're still using $f$ both as the bijection between the two spaces of functions and as a dummy function in your norm definitions. That means you have one symbol performing two very different roles. This is considered bad practice and should be avoided at all times.

Comment: You did _not_ edit accordingly, but I've done so now. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you very much, and my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a function $g\in C[0,1]$. Let $f[g]\in C[a,b]$ be defined by $f[g](x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b-a}}g(\frac{x-a}{b-a})$. You should be able to prove that's an isometry just by u-substitution!

The basic idea is, you translate/stretch the function so that it covers the new interval, then renormalize it to give it the same norm as before. You can apply the same idea to the other norms. Stretching it is the same, the only thing that differs is the renormalization factor. For example: the $\sup$ norm doesn't need renormalization.

Comment: Using consistent notation in the question and the answer would be clearer.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want to untangle all the notation in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=y$ where $y(t) = x\left( \dfrac{t-a}{b-a} \right)\cdot\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{b-a}}$ for $a\le t\le b$.  Then
$$
\|y\|_2^2=\int_a^b (y(t))^2\,dt=\int_a^b \left(x\left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)\right)^2 \frac{dt}{b-a} = \int_0^1 (x(u))^2\,du = \| x \|_2^2
$$

Let $g(x)=z$ where $z(t)= x\left( \dfrac{t-a}{b-a} \right)$  Then
$$
\|z\|_\infty = \sup_{a\le t\le b} |z(t)| = \sup_{0\le u\le 1} |x(u)| = \|z\|_\infty.
$$

In both of these, the substitution $u = \dfrac{t-a}{b-a}$ is used.